# Plain JavaScript - ScrollIntoView inside Div

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have the requirement to scroll a certain element inside a div (**not a direct child**) into view.

---

Basically I need the same functionality as [ScrollIntoView](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_scrollintoview.asp) provides, but for a specified parent (only this parent should scroll).
Additionally it is not possible for me to use any 3rd party libraries.

---

I am not quite sure on how to approach this problem, as I do very limited JavaScript development. Is there someone that could help me out?

---

I found [this code](https://github.com/Arwid/jQuery.scrollIntoView/blob/master/jquery.scrollIntoView.js) that would do exactly what I need, but unfortunately it requires JQuery and I was not able to translate it to plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I think I have a start for you. When you think about this problem you think about getting the child div into the viewable area of the parent. One naive way is to use the child position on the page relative to the parent's position on the page. Then taking into account the scroll of the parent. Here's a possible implementation.

```
function scrollParentToChild(parent, child) {

  // Where is the parent on page
  var parentRect = parent.getBoundingClientRect();
  // What can you see?
  var parentViewableArea = {
    height: parent.clientHeight,
    width: parent.clientWidth
  };

  // Where is the child
  var childRect = child.getBoundingClientRect();
  // Is the child viewable?
  var isViewable = (childRect.top >= parentRect.top) && (childRect.bottom <= parentRect.top + parentViewableArea.height);

  // if you can't see the child try to scroll parent
  if (!isViewable) {
        // Should we scroll using top or bottom? Find the smaller ABS adjustment
        const scrollTop = childRect.top - parentRect.top;
        const scrollBot = childRect.bottom - parentRect.bottom;
        if (Math.abs(scrollTop) < Math.abs(scrollBot)) {
            // we're near the top of the list
            parent.scrollTop += scrollTop;
        } else {
            // we're near the bottom of the list
            parent.scrollTop += scrollBot;
        }
  }

}
```

Just pass it the parent and the child node like this:

```
scrollParentToChild(parentElement, childElement)
```

Added a demo using this function on the main element and even nested elements

https://jsfiddle.net/nex1oa9a/1/

Comment: Thank you, this helped me as a start!

Comment: thanks, you saved me! Was trying to achieve this for 3h, wonderful! thanks again!

Comment: Change the second part of the `isViewable` test to `(childRect.bottom <= parentRect.top + parentViewableArea.height)` to have it work more reliably. With `childRect.top` you can have just a pixel of the child visible and it won't scroll.

Comment: I spent a couple of days using `animate({scrollTop})` to have scrolling on a `<select>` with the keyboard, worked with some issues.

This worked like a charm, Thanks,

Comment: This function works well, especially for fixed or sticky position parent elements like a sidebar. I had a scenario where a relative positioned parent element may not be in view in the browser window. The child element was scrolled into view of the parent but the child was still "off screen" since the parent was partially or fully not in the view in browser window.

Comment: Pairing this function with the CSS property [scroll-behavior: smooth;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) on the parent element allows for the child element to smoothly scroll into view in the parent. If a browser like Safari doesn't support this property then the browser will default to the normal behavior of simply "jumping" directly to a scroll position.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to center the child inside the parent element, regardless of the location on screen, you can use something like:

```js
function centerInParent(parent, child) {
  var parentRect = parent.getBoundingClientRect();
  var childRect = child.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  parent.scrollLeft += (childRect.left - parentRect.left) - (parent.clientWidth / 2);
  parent.scrollTop += (childRect.top - parentRect.top) - (parent.clientHeight / 2);
}
```

But this requires that there is enough scrolling possible (up/down & left/right) inside the parent element.

Comment: Hi i3ene! There is a typo in your function, when you set `childRect`. This should be set to `child.getBoundingClientRect()` and NOT `element.getBoundingClientRect()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some easy stuff like:

```
function customScroll(id) {
    window.location.href = "#mydiv"+id;
}
```

Basically `window.location.href` should help you.

Comment: btw the idea of "id" is that you can GETURL parameter - a bit advanced using. Just try the window.location.href = "mydiv".

Comment: Wouldn't this scroll the complete page? I edited the question. For me it would be important that only the specified parent scrolls.

Comment: Okay now I got it - just jump inside the parent is your requirement. Then you need additional CSS.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality can be achieved in some few steps.
First you get the position of the child using `childElement.getBoundingClientRect();`
which will return the following values

```
bottom : val
height: val
left: val
right: val
top: val
width: val
```

Then just position the child element according to the top left values into the parent element keeping child elements `position` as `absolute`. The parent Element's `position` must be `relative` type to place the child properly and get the effect of `ScrollIntoView`.

```
childElement.style.position = 'absolute';
childElement.style.top = 'value in px';
childElement.style.left = 'value in px';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I'ts worked for me fine.

```
onArrowUp() {
    this.focus === null ? this.focus = 0 : (this.focus > 0 ? this.focus-- : null);
    this.items[this.focus].scrollIntoView({block: "nearest", behavior: "smooth"})
}

onArrowDown() {
    this.focus === null ? this.focus = 0 : (this.focus < this.items.length - 1 ? this.focus++ : null);        
    this.items[this.focus].scrollIntoView({block: "nearest", behavior: "smooth"})
}
```

Methods `onListUp` and `onListDown` should be called when pressed Up and Down arrows. The `focus` is current element id of elements array. The `items` is array of list DOM elements.