# How to make scroll inside the div with scrollIntoView without scrolling the whole page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, scroll

There is the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mr_blond97/bf0ja1rp/)

The code is:

```
scrollToElement() {
   document.getElementById("elem-17").scrollIntoView();
}
```

The html is:

```
<button (click)="scrollToElement()">Scroll To 8th Element</button>
<div class="wrapper">
    <li *ngFor="let item of itemList; let i = index" id="elem-{{i}}">{{item}}</li>
</div>
```

The css is:

```
.wrapper {
    height: 200vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

The method scrollIntoView scrolls the "wrapper" div and when the div hasn't big height. But when the div height bigger then page viewport it does scroll the whole page. How to make scroll in div witout scrolling the page?

Comment: What is the code for `scrollToElement()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45408920/plain-javascript-scrollintoview-inside-div

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plain JavaScript - ScrollIntoView inside Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45408920/plain-javascript-scrollintoview-inside-div)