# Scroll to a programmatically selected row in a v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a map with features on it that are also listed in a v-data-table. When the user clicks a row, the feature is highlighted on the map. When the user clicks a map feature, the corresponding grid row is selected. So I am programmatically setting the selected row like this:

```
selectRow(id) {
  this.selected = [this.getRowFromId(id)]
},

getRowFromId(id) {
  for (let site of this.sites) {
    if (site.id === id) return site;
  }
  return []
},
```

Works fine with one UX problem: The table is not scrolled to the selected row.

I am using a vertically scrolling data-table with all rows in the grid rather than pagination.

Any ideas on how to programmatically scroll the data table?

Comment: maybe try using ref to select an element ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. I found most of what I was looking for in this post: [Plain JavaScript - ScrollIntoView inside Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45408920/plain-javascript-scrollintoview-inside-div)

I had to do a couple of v-data-grid specific things to make it work. I am using a watcher in my context but you could to this anywhere you needed to:

```js
    watch: { 
      selectedId: function(newVal) { // watch it
        // Select the row
        this.selectRow(newVal)
        // Scroll the item into view
        // First we need to let the component finish selecting the row in the background
        setTimeout( () => {
            // We get the selected row (we assume only one or the first row)
            const row = document.getElementsByClassName("v-data-table__selected")[0]
            // Then we get the parent. We need to give the -v-data-table a ref
            // and we actually take the child of the table element which 
            // has the scrollbar in my case.
            const parent = this.$refs.detailGrid.$el.firstChild
            // Finally call the scroll function
            this.scrollParentToChild(parent, row )
        }, 100)
      }
    },
    methods: {
      scrollParentToChild(parent, child) {
        // Where is the parent on page
        var parentRect = parent.getBoundingClientRect();
        // What can you see?
        var parentViewableArea = {
          height: parent.clientHeight,
          width: parent.clientWidth
        };
        // Where is the child
        var childRect = child.getBoundingClientRect();
        // Is the child viewable?
        var isViewable = (childRect.top >= parentRect.top) && (childRect.top <= parentRect.top + parentViewableArea.height);
        // if you can't see the child try to scroll parent
        if (!isViewable) {
          // scroll by offset relative to parent
          parent.scrollTop = (childRect.top + parent.scrollTop) - parentRect.top - childRect.height
        }
      },
    }
```